# Ошибка драйвера при подключении к БД из метода сервлета doGet , из любого другого класса работает

Tags: java, servlet, jdbc

Получаю из БД данные

```
public  class ConnectDB {
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb";
    static final String USER = "user";
    static final String PASS = "password";

    public ArrayList<User> getUsers(){
        ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);) {
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
            while (resultSet.next()){
                String firstName = resultSet.getString("firstName");
                String lastName = resultSet.getString("lastName");
                User user = new User(firstName,lastName);
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error to method  select()"+e);
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

Метод getUsers() работает , но только не из сервлета.
Если вызвать его в сервлете даже через обертку все равно выходит следующая ошибка

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй добавить данный кусок кода перед connection

```
   // register JDBC driver, optional, since java 1.6
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

либо так

```
static {
    loadDriver();
}

private static void loadDriver() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.